# Запуск Anaconda в Linux не из терминала

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

Установил Anaconda на Линукс.Все встало нормально,но во всех рекаомендациях по установке и запуску написано,что запускать ее можно только из терминала.Очень неудобно.Терминал занят во время работы анаконды,соответственно ничего через него сделать нельзя.Если его закрыть,тосоответственно закрывается и Анаконда и все,что я через нее запускал.
Есть ли другой способ запустить Анаконду?

Comment: Откройте ещё вкладку в терминале, если он это позволяет. Или ещё десять вкладок. Или сто. Если не позволяет - то ещё десять терминалов. Или сто. Это на пассаж о том, что терминал занят. По основному вопросу ответить не могу.

Comment: Вроде были же средства, позволяющие в фоне процессы запускать. Что-то типа `nohup script.py > script.log 2>&1 &`